# HTTPServletResponse messes up UTf-8

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

I have an utf-8 encoded string and want to respond this string as answer for an http-request via a java http servlet, but the browser just receives messed up special characters.

If I print the same string to a file via FileOutputStream the characters are handled correctly.

So the HttpServletResponse-Writer changes for example the german character "Ä" from the correct notation 0xC3A4 to 0xC383C2A4.

In the following code "response" is the HttpServletResponse object and "result" the string.

```
try {       
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(result);
    out.close();

    Writer fileOut = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("outputfile")));
    fileOut.write(result);
    fileOut.close();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why does the HttpServletResponse manipulate the string and does not just pass the character encoding untouched like the BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream)) does?

Thanks,
Chemo.

Comment: What is `result` here?

Comment: Your test case is bogus. You're not telling `OutputStreamWriter` to use UTF-8. It's this way using platform default encoding which apparently "works" for you. You need to pass it as 2nd constructor argument of `OutputStreamWriter` as in `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("outputfile"), "UTF-8")`.  Then, you can start asking/complaining.

Comment: I already did that. If I demand the UTF-8-encoding in the OutputStreamWriter as you propose, the result is identical to the HttpServletResponse: special characters are getting messed up.

Answer (score 1):

While not an answer to your question, you should know that an `HttpServletResponse` also has a method to get a plain, bare-bones, raw `OutputStream`.
If you are sure your contents are actually in UTF-8, and your `result` is a string here, just do:

```
final OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream;
out.write(result.getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush(); // probably not needed but it never hurts
```

You will avoid all transformations that the given `PrintWriter` could forcefeed upon you.

Comment: Great. I tryed that and the result stayed the same (messed up special characters). But when I deleted the "UTF-8"-demand (like I leaved that out with the file output before) the server output is being UTF-8-encoded correctly. Does that mean the string text is encoded in UTF-8 but the string is not correctly flagged?

But anyhow, thanks, that solves my problem.

Comment: No, this indicates that the `result` is not in UTF-8 at all. You've then actually a bigger problem.

Comment: I cannot rule that out. But how does it come, that the output (both, file output via OutputStream and server output via OutputStream) is in correct UTF-8-encoding if "result" isn't even encoded in UTF-8 and I do not demand UTF-8 encoding in the OutputStream - constructors?

Comment: What is the source of your `result` here?

Comment: "result" is a by an xml library composed string of json-values that my server gets from another server via an http-request. I get the same behaviour if I output (to a file or as a http-response) the untouched json-values.

Comment: An _XML_ library to manipulate _JSON_? Why don't you just ditch the XML part??

Comment: the output is requested in a special xml schema. I also don't think this is the source of the problem, because the output behaves that strange with the untouched json-string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file you're passing to the outputstream is not using UTF-8 as encoding. I think you should check on that.